# No se ejecuta el objeto como un Arreglo

Tags: java, array

Tengo este proyecto en donde tengo que hacer un objeto en forma de arreglo y donde en cada posicion del arreglo el objeto debe ejecutar un metodo, pero el objeto no ejecuta el metodo y me sale error

Este es el Main

```
  int i;
      int cantidad;
      cantidad=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados"));
      Employess employees[] = new Employess[cantidad];
     
      
      for(i=0; i<cantidad; i++)
      {
          System.out.println(i);
          employees[i].registerEmployee(); //En esta linea me aparece el error
      }
```

Esta es la clase del metodo

```
public class Employess {
    String employeeName;
    int employeeID;
    
    public void registerEmployee()
    {
        employeeName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del empleado");
        employeeID=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el ID del empleado: " + employeeName));
    }
}
```

Apreciaría mucho su ayuda

Comment: creo que no estas instanciando los empleados dentro del array, intenta imprimir cada elemento del array

Comment: ¿Que error te sale exactamente? Podrias copiarlo?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at proyecto2docuatrimestre.Main.main(Main.java:29)

Answer (score 1):

La sola creación del arreglo no inicializa todos sus campos con instancias de la clase `Employess`, por lo tanto todos sus campos están en `null`. Debes crear el objeto primero antes de invocar al método `registerEmployee` y luego lo almacenas dentro del arreglo:

```
...
for(i=0; i<cantidad; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
    Employess employee = new Employess();
    employee.registerEmployee();
    employees[i] = employee;
}
...
```

O en una sola línea:

```
...
for(i=0; i<cantidad; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
    (employees[i] = new Employess()).registerEmployee();
}
...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio mucho su ayuda, gracias!:)